# gtk 3 new app use old command line arguments

Tags: c, linux, gtk3

Here is my code:

```
void main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    //Создаем окно
    GtkApplication *app;
    app = gtk_application_new( "org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_signal_connect( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( showWindow ), argv[1] );
    g_application_run( G_APPLICATION( app ), 0, NULL );
    g_object_unref( app );
}
```

I want to send some char* argument (  argv[1] ) to window widget. And that code is works. If I start my program, like:

```
./myapp here_some_string
```

argv[1] sends to my window widget without a problem.

But, if I don't close current window, and run my application again ( another copy ) with another command line argument, there is some strange. argv[1] doesn't contains correct value, it contains old value. Why?

Example:

```
./myapp string_1 & //app gets string_1
./myapp string_2 //app gets string_1 again!
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue..

Comment: Looks like I undestand what I doing wrong. I should have change first string argument of function `gtk_application_new()`. I change my code. I get a random string and put it as first argument of `gtk_application_new()`.

Answer (score -1):

There is all my code. When I run the app in console it print the string two times. If I don't close current window, and run another app, then second app print just one string. And first app print string one more time. What is it? A bug?

```
#include "MyMain.h"


void showWindow2( GtkApplication *app, gpointer gp_data )
{
    printf( "%s\n", ( char* ) gp_data );
    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_application_window_new( app );
    gtk_widget_show_all( window );
}


void main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    printf( "%s\n", argv[1] );

    //Создаем окно
    GtkApplication *app;
    app = gtk_application_new( "org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_signal_connect( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK( showWindow2 ), argv[1] );
    g_application_run( G_APPLICATION( app ), 0, NULL );
    g_object_unref( app );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When updating your question to include more information, please use the Edit link below your original post as answer posts are only supposed to be for answers.